# CSS / jquery if() css effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Not sure why this isn't working...

I have several DIVs with an class of .rightColumnButton. A few of them have a height of 30px:

```
.rightColumnButton{
height:30px;
width:206px;
margin-top:20px;
}
```

I want to change the margin-top to 10px if they have a height of 30px:

```
$(function(){

if($( '.rightColumnButton' ).css("height") == "30"){
    $(this).animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500);


    }    
} );
```

Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `css('height')` returns also the unit, which usually is 'px'. So in this case, you're comparing `'30px' == '30'`. Use the `height()` method which returns a numerical value and compare that to an integer.

Also, you are not specifying what object you want to animate, as the element doesn't get 'carried' inside the `if` clause. Use the `each()` method on the element to create a closure:

```
$(function(){
    $('.rightColumnButton').each(function() {
        if($(this).height() == 30) {
            $(this).animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500);
        }    
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Instead of writing in the comments, I thought I'd clarify myself here. I assume your point is to animate all elements that have a height of 30px. In your original post, you had this:

```
if($( '.rightColumnButton' ).css("height") == "30"){
```

That does select all '.rightColumnButtons' allright, but when you use the `css("height")` call, you are getting only the height of the first element. If your code had worked, it would have animated all of the divs *only if the first div* had had a height of 30px.

That is where the `each()` method comes in handy. It loops through every element in the selection and compares the heights independently of each other and animates if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info, your info was spot on, but I have several divs, and I think this only checks the first one. The first three have a height of 110px, I need it to check all of them.

Comment: The `each` method will loop through all the elements which have a class 'rightColumnButton', so it checks all of them.

Comment: Thanks! Just need to remove the first "if("

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not specified

```
$(function(){
    $( '.rightColumnButton' ).each(function(){
        if($(this).css("height") == "30"){
            $(this).animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500);
        }
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: should be `each` instead of `foreach` :)

Answer (score 1):

the `css()` method will return a string with units, in your case '30px';

So you have to check for

```
$('.rightColumnButton').css("height") == "30px"
```

or use the height() function:

```
$('.rightColumnButton').height() == 30
```

You also need to define `this` before animating.

```
var col = $('.rightColumnButton');
if (col.height() == 30) {
    col.animate({marginTop: "10px"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
$(function(){
    if($( '.rightColumnButton' ).css("height") == "30px"){
      $(this).animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500);
    }    
} );
```

If it doesn't work, try putting an alert for the content of :

```
$('.rightColumnButton').css("height")
```

... and pasting the result here.

Comment: I see part of my problem. The first three Divs .rightColumnButton have a height of 110px, the rest have a height of 30px. It's only checking the first one, I need it to loop. Thanks for the suggestion on the alert, it returns 110px.

Comment: Any suggestions on running a loop through all the .rightColumnButton ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the $('rightColumnButton').css...  returns a collection of values, and your if is comaring that to 30.

Try something like this instead:

```
$("rightColumnButton").each(function (i) {
    if (this.height == 30) 
        $(this).animate({marginTop: "10px"}, 500);
}
```